# Dash search function does not work in 11.10 after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search function doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72527/dash-search-function-doesnt-work)

The search function does not work in dash after upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Explain exactly what "does not work" means.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a duplicate of [Dash search function does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72527/dash-search-function-doesnt-work). So you can try [following](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853156):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity unity-common unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-gwibber unity-lens-music unity-place-applications unity-place-files unity-scope-musicstores unity-services unity-2d unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-greeter
```

Then you can just log out and back in
or `sudo restart lightdm`