# Dash search function doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Every other time I reboot, I loose my applications lens in Unity!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93893/every-other-time-i-reboot-i-loose-my-applications-lens-in-unity)

It was working about an hour ago, now it doesn't give any results (even for "firefox" for example). What's wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, I did. This problem occured when I added pidging to the startup manager.

Comment: This may answer it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34902/search-results-in-unity-are-always-empty

Comment: Searching files works - but I still can't search through apps ("terminal", "firefox" or "evolution" don't give any results).

Comment: If you press `super+a` (Windows logo key) this will open the Applications search, does your search give results there?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  Selecting "Applications" just results in an empty box and no searches come up with any applications.

I finally found this solution:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853156

I ran the command that begins:
"sudo apt-get install --reinstall..."

I got some errors that some packages did not exist, so I just removed them from the command line and tried the command again, until it worked.

"sudo lightdm restart" gave me an error...apparently root does not have permission to access a user's display manager?  But no matter...the apt-get re-install did the trick and the next time I clicked on the dash home, the applications were all back.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Comment: Also, the right command is `sudo restart lightdm`, or you can just log out and back in.